# Searching multiple columns with a wild card value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables: Calls and Devices

Sample of Devices (93 devices in all):

```
1234
2341
3412
4123
```

My Calls table has several columns, but in 4 of the columns a value from the Devices table could exist. However those columns have text and other values in them, for example

```
1234 (Jim Jones), 5555 (Helpline)
6666 (Services), 3412 (Mike Rowe)
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can basically do a wild card search (%) using the Devices table and a "IN" statement.  It may not even be possible.

**This is not valid sql but I'm trying to get my point across:**

```
select * from Calls where Row2 LIKE IN ( select * from devices)
```

I just can't wrap my head around this.  Any input please.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a space after each number in `Calls.Row2`, you could try something like this.

```
select distinct c.*
from calls c join devices d 
     on charindex(convert(varchar(10), d.deviceid) + ' ', c.row2)>0
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d55e0/3)**

**UPDATE:** Select list is distinct to avoid duplicate records as per @Shiva 's comment

Comment: This fails if a row has more than 1 matching DeviceID. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d55e0/1 I guess you can fix it by doing a DISTINCT in the SELECT

Comment: @Shiva, agree, it will bring duplicate records. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really recommend this, but this should do what you want:

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM Calls C
INNER JOIN devices D
    ON C.Row2 LIKE '%' + D.Col1 + '%'
```